# tor high traffic p2p

Tags: torsocks

There are these "don't use tor for bittorent" and "bitcoin over tor is not a good idea" statements. I wonder if that is only valid because it is mixed traffic, where you have users with ip addresses and users with .onion addreses. This would mean that for the users with ip addreses you need to run the traffic over the limited exit nodes. But would a network for torrents or file storage or any kind which would require high traffic work over tor, if all peers run as hidden services with .onion addreses?

Comment: There are performance issues like you mentioned (the network has limited capacity), but there are also privacy issues as well. For example, Tor does not proxy UDP, so it's easy to accidentally leak your bittorrent UDP traffic.

Comment: I'm not sure if UDP would be neccesary, I'm talking about nodes which all communicate via socket transport. every node would be a hidden service, so no traffic over clear net would be required.

Comment: Ah sorry I misunderstood your question, thanks for clarifying.